# In autoconf, how to create temporary files and test shell command?

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf

In my configure.ac, I'd like to create a temporary file (a Makefile), and execute something (make). To verify some defined variables in some includes (it does not matter here).

Of course I can create /tmp/Makefile, cd /tmp, make, etc... But I need to clean, create maybe a random subfolder so I don't overwrite a Makefile there, etc.

But Isn't there something like AC_TRY_COMPILE? But does not try to compile, just runs something instead. Clearly AC_TRY_*** embeds a way to create a temporary file, remove it, etc. I saw reference $ac_tmp or $tmp but that does not get replaced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> In my configure.ac, I'd like to create a temporary file (a Makefile),
> and execute something (make). To verify some defined variables in some
> includes (it does not matter here).

That `make` needs to be involved in that sounds extremely fishy to me, but I'll take the question at face value.

> Of course I can create /tmp/Makefile, cd /tmp, make, etc... But I need
> to clean, create maybe a random subfolder so I don't overwrite a
> Makefile there, etc.

The particulars are still sounding fishy ....

> But Isn't there something like AC_TRY_COMPILE? But does not try to
> compile, just runs something instead. Clearly AC_TRY_*** embeds a way
> to create a temporary file, remove it, etc. I saw reference $ac_tmp or
> $tmp but that does not get replaced correctly.

No, Autoconf has no built-in, user-facing macro for running arbitrary shell commands.  Why would it?  One would normally just write the commands literally into the Autoconf input.  There is `AC_RUN_IFELSE`, but that serves a more specialized purpose than you describe: not to run an arbitrary command, but to compile provided source code to a program and run *that*.

But your focus seems to be slipping here. You started out asking about creating temporary files, and now you've shifted to running commands.  The two are not closely connected.  In particular, yes, Autoconf `configure` scripts do create and remove temporary files in conjunction with performing certain tests that execute specific commands, but they use pre-defined, (reasonably) well-known names for these, and it does not sound like that would serve your purpose.

On the other hand, [Section 11.15 of the Autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/autoconf.html#Limitations-of-Usual-Tools), "Limitations of the Usual Tools", addresses exactly your question about temporary files and directories in its discussion of the `mktemp` command:

> Shell scripts can use temporary files safely with `mktemp`, but it does
> not exist on all systems. A portable way to create a safe temporary
> file name is to create a temporary directory with mode 700 and use a
> file inside this directory. Both methods prevent attackers from
> gaining control, though `mktemp` is far less likely to fail gratuitously
> under attack.
>
> Here is sample code to create a new temporary directory ‘$dir’ safely:
>
> ```
>     # Create a temporary directory $dir in $TMPDIR (default /tmp).
>     # Use mktemp if possible; otherwise fall back on mkdir,
>     # with $RANDOM to make collisions less likely.
>     : "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}"
>     {
>       dir=`
>        (umask 077 && mktemp -d "$TMPDIR/fooXXXXXX") 2>/dev/null
>       ` &&
>       test -d "$dir"
>     } || {
>       dir=$TMPDIR/foo$$-$RANDOM
>     
>       (umask 077 && mkdir "$dir")
>     } || exit $?
> ```

And in case you wanted more than a simple "no" about there being a built-in macro for this, it is unlikely that the manual would bother with discussing the details if there were a built-in macro that already did it for you.

Comment: Yes the make is fishy, but I need to get the CFLAGS exported by a library (DPDK). The only way to get them is through an include of a complex graph of *their* Makefile. They're moving to pkg-config but meanwhile, I still need to support their Make system. It's pretty specific, I agree. But overwise I wouldn't be asking.
It is kind of two things yes, but the AC_RUN_IFELSE does nearly the same two things too.